# I am trying to use vbscript to pull the path out of a registry export and use that path to add the Outlook PST file to outlook automatically

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I have already run a batch file on all of our users to regexport a key that has all of the PST locations for Outlook. The issue is that it exports in a way that makes it hard to read each line into my current script and add everything into outlook. Is there a way to read the paths from this:

```
    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Search\Catalog]
    "C:\\Users\\tratliff\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Outlook\\OutlookData File - Default.ost"=hex:b4,\
      0e,02,00,00,00,00,00
    "C:\\Users\\tratliff\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Outlook\\trevor.ratliff@company.com - default.ost"=hex:cc,\
      e1,01,00,00,00,00,00
    "C:\\Users\\tratliff\\Documents\\Outlook Files\\archive.pst"=hex:3c,6a,00,00,\
      00,00,00,00
    "C:\\Users\\tratliff\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Outlook\\tratliff@company.com - default.ost"=hex:a0,\
      e9,24,00,00,00,00,00
    "C:\\Users\\tratliff\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Outlook\\tratliff@company.com - trevor.ost"=hex:c4,\
      05,23,00,00,00,00,00
    "C:\\Users\\tratliff\\Documents\\Outlook Files\\archive1.pst"=hex:64,11,00,00,\
      00,00,00,00
    "C:\\Users\\tratliff\\Documents\\Outlook Files\\backup.pst"=hex:70,04,07,00,00,\
      00,00,00
    "C:\\Users\\tratliff\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Outlook\\trevor.ratliff@company.com - hii-tsd.ost"=hex:bc,\
      12,0f,00,00,00,00,00
    "C:\\Users\\tratliff\\Documents\\Outlook Files\\archive2.pst"=hex:84,07,00,00,\
      00,00,00,00
    "C:\\Users\\tratliff\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Outlook\\trevor.ratliff@company.com - ter.ost"=hex:fc,\
      a0,00,00,00,00,00,00
```

Into something similar to this where I can create a for loop and read each line as a path to input into this?

```
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objnet = CreateObject("wscript.network")
    Set olkApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    userProfilePath = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserProfile%")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(userProfilePath & "\documents\Outlook Files")
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
       If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) = "pst" Then
         olkApp.Session.AddStore objFile.Path
       End If
    Next
    MsgBox "Done"
```